# How to print strings from an array using a for loop based on user input

Tags: java

This is a basic version of the current code i have (be warned i'm new so the stupidity you are about to see will make you mad XD).

```
package prjWebinar2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clsPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String answer;
        String date;
        String time;

        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] video = {"abc", "bce", "cde"};

        System.out.println("Option 1:" + video[0]);
        System.out.println("Would you like to use option1?");
        answer = option.nextLine();

        if(option.equals("yes")) {
            if(option.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
                date = option.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
                time = option.nextLine();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Option 2:" + video[1]);
                System.out.println("Would you like to use this video?");
                answer = option.nextLine();

                if(option.equals("yes"))   {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
                    date = option.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
                    time = option.nextLine();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("final option, option 3:" + video[2]);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to use this video?");
                    answer = option.nextLine();

                    if(option.equals("yes")) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
                        date = option.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
                        time = option.nextLine();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("We do not have an other options for videos");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can implement a for loop instead of using `if` and `else`. I need a loop that will print the first value of the array and then only print the second and third based on the user input. May sound vague but I basically want the loop to print the first option, if the user then enters no then the second option is printed etc. 
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks, Orson.

Comment: Use a `do-while` loop

Comment: what if instead of printing "wanna play 1?, wanna play 2?, wanna play 3?#, you just print the whole option list and the user type an integer (1,2,3...) and you use this integer as an index to get the right object in your list? That would remove a lot of code duplication and you wouldn't need a loop

Comment: @jhamon that would be the correct solution, however on the actual code the 3 options are much longer than 'abc' and so there would be too much information on screen. I have just broken the code down so that there isnt so much.

Comment: yea, that's make it even more useful. Let's say you have 50 options. What would take most place: a 50 options list or 50 times `"Option 1: blabla, \n Would you like to use this video?"` and think of the user experience, it's way easier to just type a number rather than to to type multiple "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private void answerYes(String video) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
        String date = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
        String time = sc.nextLine();

        // Do something with this
        System.out.println(String.format("You have chosen date: %s and time: %s", date, time));
    }

    private void showOptions(String[] videos, String noMoreVideosMsg) {
        int currentVideoIdx = 0;
        while (currentVideoIdx < videos.length) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Option %d: %s", currentVideoIdx + 1, videos[currentVideoIdx]));
            System.out.println("Would you like to use this video? (yes / no)");
            String answer = sc.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                // Choose this option
                answerYes(videos[currentVideoIdx]);
                // This will exit the function, meaning skip all further logic
                return;
            } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
                // Go to the next option
                currentVideoIdx++;
            } else {
                // Unknown command
                System.out.println(String.format("Command '%s' is not recognized", answer));
                System.out.println(); // Just a blank line for nicer output
            }
        }

        // If no option is selected, print the default message
        System.out.println(noMoreVideosMsg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String[] VIDEOS = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        final String NO_MORE_VIDEOS_MSG = "We do not have another options for videos";

        Test test = new Test();
        test.showOptions(VIDEOS, NO_MORE_VIDEOS_MSG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to loop over the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
     ....code
}
```

You can use *i* to print numbers and the corresponding videos.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Loop on the full task, asking each time the user if he wants to select the video:

```
public class clsPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer;
        String date;
        String time;

        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] video = {"abc", "bce", "cde"};

        for(int id=0; id<video.length; id++) {
            System.out.println("Option id:" + video[id]);
            System.out.println("Would you like to use option1?");
            answer = option.nextLine();

            if(option.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
                date = option.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
                time = option.nextLine();
                break; // stop looping
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The loop will stop at the `break` instruction. If the user doesn't input `yes` the loop block does nothing and prompts the next video element.

**Option 2**: Display the full list then ask the user to type the option number.

```
public class clsPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer = -1;
        String date;
        String time;

        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] video = {"abc", "bce", "cde"};

        for(int id=0; id<video.length; id++) {
            System.out.println("Option id:" + video[id]);
        }

        System.out.println("Which option would you like to use?");
        answer = option.nextInt();

        if(answer>0 && answer<video.length) {
            System.out.println("Video selected:"+answer);
            System.out.println("Please enter a date you would like to show the video:");
            date = option.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a time you would like to show the video:");
            time = option.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it way faster to use as you won't have to decline N-1 items before finding the Nth item.

In both case, incorrect user inputs are not handled. I let you do this part.